# Exception thrown: read access violation. this->top was nullptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, linked-list, stack

I am currently trying to develop a RPM Calculator using C++ but I am running into this error message whenever I try to run my code

> Exception thrown: read access violation. this->top was nullptr.

Here is what I have in my .h file:

```
template<class T>
struct MyStack
{
    T data; // this is going to store the number
    MyStack<T>* link; // used to point to the next element in the stack
    
private:
    MyStack<T>* top = NULL; // this will represent the top of the stack when the stack is empty this is set to null
public:
    void push(T operand);
    void value();
    void pop();
};

template<class T>
void MyStack<T>::push(T value) 
{
    MyStack<T>* ptr = new MyStack<T>; // create a new pointer
    ptr->data = value;  // set data to whatever the value that is passed in
    ptr->link = top; 
    top = ptr;
}


template<class T>
void MyStack<T>::value()
{
    if (top->data != NULL) { // here is where the error occurs
        cout << top->data << ">" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "X>";
    }// prints out the current top value
}


template<class T>
void MyStack<T>::pop()
{
    MyStack<T>* ptr = top; // creating the pointer
    top = top->link; //. top is now equal to the link
    delete(ptr); // I can now delete the top value as top is now equal to the link which is the previos value
}
```

And here is what I have in my main

```
int main() 
{
    
    MyStack<double> s;
    string input;

    while (true) {
        // display prompt
        s.value();
    //    cout << "VALUE>";

        // get input
        cin >> input;

        // check for numeric value
        double num;
        if (istringstream(input) >> num) {
            s.push(num);
        }
        // check for operator
        else if (isOperator(input)) {
            performOp(input, s);
        }

        // check for quit
        else if (input == "q") {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
        }
    }
    

    
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this? I have been trying to fix this all day but haven't been able to do it.
NOTE: I have removed some other functions I had so the code was not too long
any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: My attention was drawn to `if (top->data != NULL)` by a compiler warning (*warning: NULL used in arithmetic*) suggesting that this line wasn't quite kosher. That something not a pointer was being tested as though it was a pointer. Don't ignore the warnings. They can save you a lot of debugging even when you don't quite understand what the warning means. Stop and puzzle it out because it will be easier than trying to figure out what's going wrong after the fact.

Comment: Side note: It appear that `MyStack` is both the stack and the linked nodes that make up the stack. This might be putting too much responsibility on one class.

Comment: glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is calling `s.value()` on its 1st iteration when `s` is empty, so the `s.top` field is still `NULL`, but `value()` (and also `pop()`) tries to access `top->data` (and `top->link`) regardless of whether `top` is `NULL` or not.

You need to fix your `MyStack` methods to work correctly on an empty stack, ie:

In `value()`:

```
if (top->data != NULL)
```

should be

```
if (top != NULL)
```

and in `pop()`:

```
top = top->link;
```

should be

```
if (top != NULL) top = top->link;
```

Otherwise, simply don't call `value()` (or `pop()`) when the stack is empty.  Add an `isEmpty()` method that returns `true` when `top` is `NULL`, and then call `value()` (or `pop()`) only when `isEmpty()` returns `false`:

```
if (!s.isEmpty())
    s.value();
```

Comment: That helped, thank you so much for explaining this issue perfectly to me